# Filling the 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, math, logic, puzzle

I need to fill in a 6x6 array using only one arithmetic expression, so it's gonna look like that:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1
3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2
4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3
5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4
6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: No need for So many tags !!!

Comment: Secondly **No it can't be automated with single arithmetic expression** !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single arithmatic expression, I would use nested for loops like so.

```
  int[][] myArray = new int[6][6];
  for(int ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++ )
  {
      for(int kk = 0; kk < 6; kk++ )
      {
      //math expression
          myArray[ii][kk] = (ii + kk)%6+1;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I've come to this before I read that. But with IF inside. So whenever ii+kk+1>myArray.lenght then we should subtract array lenght. Still - your solution is more elegant